# What is the purpose of newslot attribute?

Tags: c#, clr, cil

I am learning intermediate language via Common Language Infrastructure book.
It states that virtual method of type can be marked with `newslot` attribute. But that attribute really confuses me, I cannot understand its meaning.

Here is quotation:

> II.10.3 - Introducting and overriding virtual methods
>
> A virtual method of a base type is overridden by providing a direct implementation of the method 
>   (using a method definition, see §II.15.4) and not specifying it to be newslot (§II.15.4.2.3).  An existing 
>   method body can also be used to implement a given virtual declaration using the .override directive 
>   (§II.10.3.2).
>
> II.10.3.1  Introducing a virtual method
>
> A virtual method is introduced in the inheritance hierarchy by defining a virtual method (§II.15.4).  The 
>   definition can be marked newslot to always create a new virtual method for the defining class and any 
>   classes derived from it:
>
> 1) If the definition is marked newslot, the definition always creates a new virtual 
>   method, even if a base class provides a matching virtual method.  A reference to the 
>   virtual method via the class containing the method definition, or via a class derived 
>   from that class, refers to the new definition (unless hidden by a newslot definition in 
>   a derived class).  Any reference to the virtual method not via the class containing the 
>   method definition, nor via its derived classes, refers to the original definition.
>
> 2) If the definition is not marked newslot, the definition creates a new virtual method 
>   only if there is not virtual method of the same name and signature inherited from a 
>   base class.
>
> It follows that when a virtual method is marked newslot, its introduction will not affect any existing 
>   references to matching virtual methods in its base classes.

What is the meaning of phrase "definition creates a new virtual method"? I thought that introduction of virtual method always creates new method. I thought that newslot is useless attribute. Can anyone provide examples to clarify that text, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you familiar with the [`new` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) in method definitions in C#? - same sort of concept.

You're saying "this method is *not* the same as any method that my base class exposes, either now or in the future". Even where we have used the exact same name. People calling method X through variables of my base class or further up my inheritance chain get method X from my base class. People calling method X on variables of my class or classes derived from it get *this* method X (unless the derived classes introduce their own `newslot` X method)

What's key here is that at the IL level, overriding is the assumed default, if an overridable method is available:

> If the definition is not marked newslot, the definition creates a new virtual method *only if there is not virtual method of the same name and signature inherited from a base class*.

At the IL level, you can mark an override as `virtual`, whereas in C# you cannot. That's why `newslot` is the important distinguishing feature.

Comment: Can you provide code example please? It still too hard to understand for me. As for me, "new modifier" for virtual methods has no sense

Comment: @LmTinyToon - that's because the C# language rules are different from the IL rules. In IL, override is default, overrides can be marked virtual, etc.